# Given any Ruby on Rails project folder, can you tell it was Rails 2.3.5 and Ruby 1.8.7 that was used for the project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

So that if you have a Ruby Version Manager, then you can switch to that mode first before altering the project files.  (probably best)

Answer (score 1):

You can set an .rvmrc file in your project directory, so that you will automatically change to a particular ruby and gemset when you enter the directory.  Check out the [rvmrc docs](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/workflow/rvmrc/) for details.

This method doesn't infer versions from the project files, though.  If you really wanted to infer Rails version you could put a little script in your .rvmrc file:

```
RAILS_VERSION=`ruby -e "require 'config/environment'; puts RAILS_GEM_VERSION"`
```

Comment: what if you are using Windows 7 or other platforms but not using RVM?

Comment: Ah, thought you were using RVM.  Hmm... not sure how you would accomplish this on Windows.  It looks like Pik (http://github.com/vertiginous/pik) is supposed to be RVM for Windows, but I don't see anything equivalent to the project-based rvmrc file.  I really don't know much at all about Windows scripting, but I'd imagine that you could cobble something together so whenever you enter a directory a script would be executed that would set the current ruby interpreter.